How to calculate the amount of tokens a certain amount of SOL can buy in pump.fun swap?
I want to keep the SOL side fixed while buying tokens on pump.fun.
But the buy function provided by pump.fun doesn't allow for SOL to be passed as fixed side.
Even if the value is close to the amount of SOL I want to buy for it will be fine.
But I couldn't find any method of calculating this amount before hand.
If anybody here has coded for pump.fun that could be great help.
